# Create cross subdomain cookies/sessions with AngularJS & PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, session, cookies, laravel-4

My app has the following structure: there's the front-end js app (angular) on the `app.` subdomain and a backend (PHP) on the root and `api.` subdomain. My login is done via the root which stores a session cookie. The cookie is stored for all subdomains with the path "/".

Directly on the api I can get the cookie. However on the same url but via an ajax GET call from the front-end the cookie is NULL.

But using an application like Postman (chrome app) a GET request to the same URL and I can get the cookie. So it seems to be specific to my apps frontend.

Here are my settings for my angular app. I've set these defaults in my app config:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I've tested on both Chrome and FF. Can't figure out why my cookies/sessions are unavailable between my frontend and backend

**Update 20/11/2013**

I also had a problem specifically with the version Angular I was using. Because I was using `$resource` instead of just `$http`, that version of angular wasn't attaching the `withCredentials` setting to the http request when using `$resource`. Updating to the latest angularjs version has fixed my problem. Because the withCredentials was not being set my cookies weren't being sent along with the xhr request. Stupidly I hadn't checked if cookies were being sent.

Comment: Have you used the domain parameter in setCookie() in your api?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4. In my config I've set it to all subdomains and path to "/".

Comment: have you considered using html 5's browser local storage instead of cookies.

Comment: There's also the problem with my sessions not being persisted when it comes to authentication. ie. I'm logged in but not when accessing via an ajax call from my frontend.

Comment: Are you sure your CORS configuration on the server-side is correct? Show all request and response headers of the GET (and OPTIONS) request. Take a closer look at the `Access-Control-...` headers.

Comment: @iamjonesy i guess your question has now received attention :) just check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `withCredentials` attribute is not enough to have it working. The server response must have the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header.

You should also check the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, as well as other `Access-Control-...` headers in requests and responses, and make sure the OPTIONS method requests and all CORS headers are handled properly by the server.

See also: **http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/**

Comment: Thanks hadn't set credentials setting on server. Also, please see me my update to my question with a problem I was having with Angular not setting the withCredentials config setting with the $resource http wrapper

Comment: @iamjonesy Which version had you been using before?

Answer (score 4):

### Cookie visibility - explained

Here's is how a valid cookie-setting header might look like:

> Set-Cookie: name=Anshuman; Domain=www.stronia.com; Path=/

so  now, let me explain the above line.

#### Path:

`Path=/` is the default path for which a cookie is visible.
So it is as good as not specifying any path.

When we say that the path will be `/`. We mean that all the paths that are children of the path `/` can access the cookie. So, `/foo` will be able to access the cookie, `/foo/bar` will be able to access the cookie, `/foo/bar/...../anything` will be able to access the cookie too, as they're all the children of the path `/`.

Assume that the mentioned path is `/mypath`. Note that parents of the mentioned path like (`/`) or siblings like (`/myotherpath`) or children of siblings like (`/myotherpath/a/b/c`) will not get access to the cookie.

Its just the mentioned path and its children who get access to the cookie.

In short, any path that starts with the mentioned path will receive the cookie from the browser.

#### Domain:

When we say that the domain will be `www.stronia.com` we mean that all the domains that are the children of the domain `www.stronia.com` can access the cookie. So `foo.www.stronia.com` will gain access to the cookie, `bar.foo.stronia.com` will gain access to the cookie, `anything.....bar.foo.stronia.com` will also gain access to the cookie as all the above mentioned domains are children of the specified domain: `www.stronia.com`.

But note that parents of the mentioned domain like (`stronia.com` or `.com`) or siblings like (`sib.stronia.com`) or children of siblings like (`a.b.c.d.sib.stronia.com`) will not get access to the cookie.

Its just the mentioned domain and its children who get access to the cookie.

In short, any domain that ends with the mentioned domain will recieve the cookie from the browser.

---

### Your problem - solved

Now, in your case, you want the cookie to be shared by the `app.` subdomain and `api.` subdomain. So all you have to do is, use the rules that I have mentioned above to set cookie that can be received by both the subdomains.

so in php code, assuming your domain name is `yourdomain.com`:

```
setcookie ("CookieName", "CookieValue", $expirationtime , "/", "yourdomain.com");
```

In Laravel4:

```
put( 'CookieName','CookieValue', $expirationtime, '/', 'yourdomain.com');
```

If you do that, your cookie will be visible to both `app.yourdomain.com` and `api.yourdomain.com`.